# How to check if a computer is responding from C#

Tags: c#, networking, netbios

What is the easiest way to check if a computer is alive and responding (say in ping/NetBios)?
I'd like a deterministic method that I can time-limit.

One solution is simple access the share (File.GetDirectories(@"\compname")) in a separate thread, and kill the thread if it takes too long.

Comment: What port do you need to connect to?  Given firewalls --  network-wide and per-system -- a system could easily be available but seem to be not responding if you pick the wrong port to try.

Comment: BTW, I'd just like to say that when a network is involved, no "deterministic" method can exist by definition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy! Use `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace's ping facility!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

Comment: For security reason PING is one of the services that blocked at our network boundary -- along with a variety of other ports.  If available this is a good mechanism, but you'd have to know if it was going to work first and that it won't be turned off in the future.

Comment: In fact, this can happen to any service. Therefore, if you need reliable way to reach a service on a remote computer, you should probably consider checking it at a higher level protocol (the protocol you're specifically relying on).

Answer (score 3):

To check a specific TCP port (`myPort`) on a known server, use the following snippet. You can catch the `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` exception to indicate non available port.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
...

IPHostEntry myHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName("myserver");
IPEndPoint host = new IPEndPoint(myHostEntry.AddressList[0], myPort);

Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(host);
```

Further, specialized, checks can try IO with timeouts on the socket.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to check a computer within the own subnet you could check it using [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). Here's an example:

```
    //for sending an arp request (see pinvoke.net)
    [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SendARP(
                                        int DestIP, 
                                        int SrcIP, 
                                        byte[] pMacAddr, 
                                        ref uint PhyAddrLen);


    public bool IsComputerAlive(IPAddress host)
    {
        //can't check the own machine (assume it's alive)
        if (host.Equals(IPAddress.Loopback))
            return true;

        //Prepare the magic

        //this is only needed to pass a valid parameter
        byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
        uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

        //Let's check if it is alive by sending an arp request
        if (SendARP((int)host.Address, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen) == 0)
            return true; //Igor it's alive!

        return false;//Not alive
    }
```

See [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp) for more information.